# join clause, match or null

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have some procs I inherited that I am trying to clean up.  One of the things I see over and over in them is the following:

```
Update Table_A
Set A.ColX = B.Colx
From Table_A A
 Join Table_B B on B.col1 =A.col1
    and B.col2 = A.col2

Update Table_A
Set A.ColX = B.Colx
From Table_A A
Join Table_B B on a.col1 =b.col1
     and B.col2 is null
```

Now , I have tried to combine these to make them a single query using the following different final lines (not at the same time!):

```
1) and (B.col2 = A.col2 or B.col2 is null)
2) and (isnull(B.col2,'') = COALESCE(a.col2, ''))
```

However, it always seems to do one of the updates, not both.  I feel like I am missing something rather obvious, Is there a good way to combine these two queries?

thanks

Comment: Is the combination of `col1` and `col2` unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should work:

```
Update Table_A
Set A.ColX = B.Colx
From Table_A A
 Join Table_B B on B.col1 = A.col1
    and (B.col2 = A.col2 OR or B.col2 is null)
```

which you said you tried - but you may try it as a `SELECT` first and see what the results are.  That may shed some light on why you're not getting the results you expect.

Comment: I was running them as selects to see if they would run.  I think there might be another issue, because I just tried with a really simple one and I got the results I expected.  I need to build it up to the complex form so see what the problem is

Comment: I found that on a lot of the queries, the above did work fine.  It just one of them that is having an issue, it just happened to be the one I kept looking at!

Comment: found the problem.  The two queries I were looking at were not mutually exclusive.  The second query would overwrite some of the records from the first one!  great logic!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the following query to work in SQL Server:

```
Update A
    Set ColX = B.Colx
    From Table_A A Join
         Table_B B
         on a.col1 = b.col1 and
            (B.col2 = A.col2 or B.col2 is null);
```

Notes:

- You should use the alias defined in the `from` clause after the `update`.  My understanding is that if you use the table name and the table is not in the `from` clause without an alias, then all rows will be updated.

Although I was pretty sure that SQL Server does not support table aliases in the set, I appear to be wrong about that, as [this simple SQL Fiddle shows](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a1b8).  Perhaps this was not allowed in some ancient version of SQL Server, and the limitation just stuck with me.

Comment: Your second bullet doesn't seem to be correct.  While it may not be best practice to use a table alias in the set statement (still trying to find the answer on that) is it supported by SQL Server.

Comment: @Limey . . . You appear to be correct, so I've fixed the answer.  I was quite sure this didn't work . . . perhaps it didn't work on some old version and I never tried it again.

Comment: It does look like it may be a best practice though.  Looking at some of Microsoft's examples, they don't use the alias in the set statement.